# Python getting next line following a certain Condition

Tags: python, url, python-2.7

I am trying to find a good way to return a value in a url page.

I want that everytime "span class=" button" is listed I can grab the next line

```
"span class=" button" 
0.87
```

I want to get 0.87

I am trying:

```
 import urllib

 url = 'http://test.com'
 sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
 content = sock.read().splitlines()
 sock.close()

 for i in content:
     i = i.strip()
```

This is where I get stuck, how do I get the next line?

Comment: HTML doesn't require lines - your example is also rubbish - see @dm03515's answer and my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is HTML you could use an html parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
buttons = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'button'})
for button in buttons:
  button.nextSibling
```

this uses [`nextSibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) which looks like it has been changed to `next_sibling` in the most recent version of beautiful soup?

Python has a built in HTMLParser
if your data is

```
<span class="button">
0.87
</span>
```

you could create a class like in the [example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#example-html-parser-application)

Comment: Do you know of anyway to do this without beautiful soup?

Comment: @AdamG. are you asking if there's a way to parse ill-formed HTML data without using an HTML parser (that could at least make a best guess)!?

Comment: yea, can I get the next line of HTML without using BS4?